# SimpleJdbcInsert to table with dot in name

Tags: java, sql, simplejdbcinsert

I am trying to use SimpleJdbcInsert to a table that happens to have a dot character in its name with dbo as default schema.  I pass in a map of key values to be inserted.

```
insertMessage = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("Trades.Transaction");
insertMessage.execute((Map)message);
```

The following exception appears:

> `PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO Trades.Transaction (Uid, StreamId, Version, ValidFrom, ValidTo, IsLatest, Direction, Quantity, Notional, TradeDate, Status, Action, SettlementAmount, SettlementCurrency, AccruedInterest, BookingAccountType, BookingAccountUid, BookingAccountName, BookingAccountLegalEntityId, BookingAccountLegalEntityShortName, BookingAccountRepUid, BookingAccountRepName, BookingAccountFacilitatorUid, BookingAccountFacilitatorName, BookingAccountFacilitatorTeamCode, ContraAccountType, ContraAccountUid, ContraAccountName, ContraAccountLegalEntityId, ContraAccountLegalEntityShortName, ContraAccountRepUid, ContraAccountRepName, ContraAccountFacilitatorUid, ContraAccountFacilitatorName, ContraAccountFacilitatorTeamCode, FacingAccountType, FacingAccountUid, FacingAccountName, FacingAccountLegalEntityId, FacingAccountLegalEntityShortName, FacingAccountRepUid, FacingAccountRepName, FacingAccountFacilitatorUid, FacingAccountFacilitatorName, FacingAccountFacilitatorTeamCode, OrigSystemIsElectronicChannel, OrigSystem, OrigSystemUid, OrigSystemStatus, OrigSystemType, OrigSystemVersion, OrigSystemErrors, DestSystemUid, DestSystem, DestSystemStatus, DestSystemType, DestSystemVersion, DestSystemErrors, StpSystemUid, StpSystem, StpSystemStatus, StpSystemType, StpSystemVersion, StpSystemErrors, GatewaySystem, GatewaySystemStatus, GatewaySystemType, GatewaySystemVersion, GatewaySystemErrors, SettlementSystemUid, SettlementSystemName, SettlementSystemStatus, SettlementSystemType, SettlementSystemVersion, SettlementSystemErrors, TransactionType, Price, Obligor, Receiver, QuoteDate, EffectiveDate, MaturityDate, UnitSize, MatchedStatus, MatchedTradeId, InstrumentDescription, BookingFacilitatorTeamCode, FxClientRate, Principal, AccruedDays, SalesCommissionCode, SalesCommissionAmount, SalesCommissionRate, SalesCommissionCcy, BrokerCommissionCode, BrokerCommissionAmount, BrokerCommissionRate, BrokerCommissionCcy, MarkupCommissionCode, MarkupCommissionAmount, MarkupCommissionRate, MarkupCommissionCcy, AddOnCommissionCode, AddOnCommissionAmount, AddOnCommissionRate, AddOnCommissionCcy, PhoneConfirmInd, PhoneConfirmBy, PhoneConfirmOn, SalesManagerReview, SalesManagerReviewComments, SalesManagerReviewTime, SalesManagerReviewIndicator, TradeManagerReview, TradeManagerReviewComments, TradeManagerReviewTime, TradeManagerReviewIndicator, EnteredOn, UpdatedOn, EnteredBy, GatewaySystemUid, OrigSystemNote1, OrigSystemNote2, OrigSystemNote3, DestSystemNote1, DestSystemNote2, DestSystemNote3, GatewayAllocFlag, QuotedAmount, LastModifiedBy, OrigTransactionId, OrigMarkitWireId, ContraAccountGlobalBook, BookingAccountGlobalBook, FXSettleAmount, SettlementLocation, AssignmentFeeCd, AssignmentFeeDesc, RiskFlagCd, RiskFlagDesc, FormPurchaseCd, FormPurchaseDesc, AccruedInterestCd, AccruedInterestDesc, EcnName, EcnId, ContraAccountLocation, BookingAccountLocation, isSuppressTrade, ContraAccountTradingSystem, BookingAccountTradingSystem, isAmend, RetailCommissionCode, RetailCommissionAmount, RetailCommissionRate, RetailCommissionCcy, ContraAccountADPAccountNo, AsOfTime, ClientCommission, MarketRate, DayCount, ExecutionStatus, LinkStreamId, Spread, RfqId, isWashGen, FxRateCurrencyPair, FxRateCalcMethod, isApprovedForNewIssueAllocation, TransactionReservationId, isEligibleForTradeSync) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Transaction'.`

I believe I need a way to surround `Trade.Transaction` with [ ] characters so it interprets that as complete table name instead of `schema.tableName`.  However, if I specify those in the table name like below

```
insertMessage = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("[Trades.Transaction]");
```

a Spring exception occurs stating it can't find meta data and hence can't find column names to generate insert statement.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Thanks